# El operador lógico "and" no me funciona en Python

Tags: python, excepciones

Estoy estudiando manejo de excepciones en Python. Hice mi propia excepción creando mi propia clases hija extendida de Exception y luego utilizando un condicional y con el operador lógico "and". Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo si coloco un valor invalido y uno verdadero, lo acepta como verdadero. ¿Ustedes saben que es lo que tengo mal o como solucionarlo?

```
class HolaMundo(Exception):
def __init__(self, mensaje):
    self.messaje = mensaje
```

```
a = input("Di Hola: ")
b = input("Di Mundo: ")
try:
    resultado = a + b
    if a != "Hola" and b != "Mundo":
        raise HolaMundo("No has puesto Hola Mundo")
except Exception as e:
    print("Ocurrio un error:", e)
    print(type(e))
else:
    print("Hecho!")
    print("Resultado: " + a + " " + b)
```

Comment: En vez de `and` deberías usar `or`. Otra forma de verlo, quizás más intuitiva, es cambiar los `!=` por `==` y negar la condición global. Ahí sí que usarías  `and`. Es decir: `if not (a=="Hola" and b=="Mundo")`. Según las [leyes de De Morgan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyes_de_De_Morgan), not(X and Y) se convierte en (not X) or (not Y), de ahí tu error.

Comment: Lo entiendo mucho mejor. Gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al poner un operador `AND` solo va a levantar la excepción cuando **las dos** variables no coinciden con Hola y Mundo.

Estas pidiendo un `OR` en lugar de un `AND`: que levente excepción en cualquiera de las condiciones ( a no sea Hola, or, b no sea Mundo):

```
class HolaMundo(Exception):

    def __init__(self, mensaje):
        self.messaje = mensaje


a = input("Di Hola: ")
b = input("Di Mundo: ")
try:
    resultado = a + b
    if a != "Hola" or b != "Mundo":
        raise HolaMundo("No has puesto Hola Mundo")
except Exception as e:
    print("Ocurrio un error:", e)
    print(type(e))
else:
    print("Hecho!")
    print("Resultado: " + a + " " + b)
```

Comprobación:

```
Di Hola: ca
Di Mundo: Mundo
Ocurrio un error: No has puesto Hola Mundo
<class '__main__.HolaMundo'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias! No lo había pensado mucho, me aclaraste las cosas.

Answer (score -2):

El operador `OR`, puedes ver que hat 2 líneas unidas con `AND` y luego la `OR`. Si las 2 se cumplen, pero el `OR` (SINO) no lo cumple, no se ejecuta la función.

```
print("Beca 2022")

distancia = int(input("Introduzca distancia de residencia de estudiante en kilómetros:    "))
ingreso_familiar = float(input("Introduzca ingreso Ingreso_familiar:   "))
cantidad_hermanos = int(input("Introduzca cantidad de hermanos:    " ))

if distancia > 40 and cantidad_hermanos > 2 or ingreso_familiar <= 600:
   print("Estudiante tiene derecho a beca")
else:
   print("Estudiante no puede recibir beca")
```

Comment: Necesidad alguna de hacer 3 respuestas? mejor edita una agregando todo y elimina el resto

Comment: Por favor, familiarizate de como funciona el sitio. mira el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Gracias por las respuestas, pero ten en cuenta que tienen que responder la pregunta que se hizo... Y no hagas multiples respuestas, esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.